# Revert to normal user in Windows program with requireAdministrator in manifest?

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi

I'm trying to encapsulate a number of repetitive installation tasks into a private setup program.  The program is for in-house use setting up custom, single purpose systems for industrial users.  I need Administrator privileges to tweak a number of Windows settings for our environment and then I need to set some current user settings for the application software packages to use.

Is it possible for a Windows program (in plain C, created with Visual Studio 2017) that uses requireAdministrator in its manifest to *revert* to the user that started the program when the admin privilege is no longer needed?  I've seen this done in linux, but have been unable to find any examples (or even mentions) of this being done in Windows.  Help?  Please?

Comment: revert already running process you can not. only if use 2 different processes. however possible and continue run as elevated process - what you gain, if return to not elevated token/logon session ?

Comment: This a many times a dupe. Try some search.

Comment: Searching is easy when you know the answer.  I wasn't guessing the keywords (like "drop") that would lead to a good answer, so after a couple days of trying, I asked.  Sorry if that offends.

Comment: I pasted the title of this question into Google search box and got good hits on the front page.

Comment: I just tried the same search in Google and did not get any "good hits" (except for this page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Answer**
When I was finally able to install a clean Windows 10 on a spare system for testing and create a pure non-admin account to test with, the new, improved answer did not work.  I added a GetUserName() call after the impersonate and wrote it to the debug log to learn that the user name was the same before and after the impersonate, even though all of the functions returned success.  I can only assume that the GetShellWindow() [I also tried GetDesktopWindow(), just in case] returned a handle to an explorer/shell under the Admin context.  So, now I'm using a cleaned up (to make it plain C) version of the GetConsoleUserToken() function I found here:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/17db92be-0ebd-4b54-9e88-a122c7bc351d/strange-problem-with-wtsqueryusertoken-and-impersonateloggedonuser?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues This is working on both my development system *AND* on the clean Windows 10 non-admin user.  The function actually searches all running processes for the explorer.exe that belongs (is attached?) to the console session and while debugging it, I did see that it find more than one explorer.exe process, but only ONE is the right one.

Thanks for all of the suggestions and comments!  They gave me good ideas and put me on a path that allowed me to use better search terms to find what I needed.

To Microsoft:  This seems quite unnecessarily complex to do something that should not be difficult for an administrator-level process to do.

**New, Improved Answer:**
Following the suggestion made by eryksun, I created the following example function that shows all of the steps my program needed to get the current user key opened.  My program has requireAdministrator in the manifest, if yours does not, you might need to make changes or additions to my sample.  Here is what is working perfectly for me (but apparently not on a clean machine under a non-admin account):

```
BOOL ChangeHkcuSettings( void )
{
   BOOL     bResult = FALSE;  // HKCU was not accessed
   HWND     hwndShell;
   DWORD    dwThreadId;
   DWORD    dwProcessId;
   HKEY     hKeyUserHive;
   HANDLE   hToken;
   HANDLE   hProcess;

   hwndShell  = GetShellWindow();
   dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwndShell, &dwProcessId );
   hProcess   = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId );
   if( NULL != hProcess )
   {
      if( OpenProcessToken( hProcess,
                            TOKEN_QUERY
                          | TOKEN_DUPLICATE
                          | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE,
                            &hToken ) )
      {
         if( ImpersonateLoggedOnUser( hToken ) )
         {
            if( ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenCurrentUser( KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKeyUserHive ) )
            {
               // ... use the user hive key to access necessary HKCU items ...
               RegCloseKey( hKeyUserHive );
               bResult = TRUE;   // HKCU was accessed
            }
            RevertToSelf();
         }
         CloseHandle( hToken );
      }
      CloseHandle( hProcess );
   }
   return bResult;
}
```

Thanks again to eryksun for the suggestion!

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** I think I found another way that will work for me...  Instead of using HKEY_CURRENT_USER (which will be the Administrator) the admin account can open the specific user's registry key(s) under HKEY_USERS instead.  I will need to find the appropriate user's SID, but my setup knows the user's name (and password, for setting auto logon), so I think this is do-able.  For me, this is much easier, since all of the code already exists in a single program that formerly write EVERYTHING to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which was easy and worked great.  Trying to be "correct" is much more work, perhaps more than it should be!  :-(

Comment: Administrators can impersonate a SYSTEM logon that's nearly all powerful, but this still can't subvert policies that are hard-coded in the kernel. Windows subsystem processes are not allowed to change the process token in flight, even if the caller has SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege. This has been enforced since Vista, for which the `NtSetInformationProcess` system call returns `STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED` if you try to set the `ProcessAccessToken` information for an already initialized Windows process. Assigning the access token is only possible for new processes.

Comment: I'd use impersonation rather than the user's SID string, so you're modifying the user's registry as the user rather than as an administrator. You can get the user token from the shell window (e.g. `GetShellWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, `OpenProcess`,  `OpenProcessToken`). Impersonate this access token and call `RegOpenCurrentUser` to open the user's registry hive.

Comment: I have implemented the method I described and it is working, but there may be some registry key ownership/permission issues that I have not yet discovered.  Thanks, eryksun, I will start reading about RegOpenCurrentUser and what I need to do to impersonate the current user.  (FWIW, the original version of this setup program actually CREATED the user account, too, but back then everything was in HKLM.)

Comment: FWIW, I found the idea for HKEY_USERS on a Microsoft forum, marked as the answer to a similar question.  You can see it here:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6536e34-efee-4b43-b189-8f2e41151d75/uac-elevation-and-writing-to-hkeycurrentuser?forum=windowscompatibility

Comment: I'd roll up `GetShellWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, and `OpenProcess` as `OpenShellProcess(DWORD dwDesiredAccess, BOOL bInheritHandle)`. I'd roll up `OpenProcessToken` and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` as `ImpersonateProcessUser(HANDLE hProcess)`. Then I'd roll these two up as `ImpersonateShellUser`, which gets paired with `RevertToSelf`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

A way given awhile back is to track down the running instance of explorer, and spawn a remote thread in it (with CreateRemoteThread) that does what you want. However CreateRemoteTherad is touchy and what if explorer isn't running?

If you know the username you can use CreateService() to create a service that runs as that user and ServiceStart() to start it but that's its own pain and now the code has to deal with no access to the desktop. Getting code running as the user on the desktop involves digging into the undocumented.

The correct design is to use two executables, the first with asInvoker that starts the second with requireAdministrator using the API call ShellExecuteEx, waits for it to finish, checks the exit code, and on success does the individual user steps.

Comment: In the early days of Vista/UAC this was recommended for setup programs and this technique had a specific name but I can't find that page on MSDN anymore.

Comment: FYI, the "Explorer" task is also the Windows Desktop, so it is just about ALWAYS present unless the system is broken or customized far, far beyond anything we will build.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to de-elevate a running process. You might be able to lower your rights a little bit but not all the way. Even if it was possible, you would have to hardcode the list of groups and privileges to remove/disable in your token because I don't believe there is a API to restrict a token just like UAC does.

There are many half-assed solutions out there to start a un-elevated  child process:

- [Using the Task Scheduler](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16796/Riding-the-Vista-UAC-elevator-up-and-down)
- [`IShellDispatch2::ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774138(v=vs.85).aspx) [in the "main" Explorer.exe instance](https://web.archive.org/web/20170104213424/http://brandonlive.com/2008/04/27/getting-the-shell-to-run-an-application-for-you-part-2-how/)
- `CreateProcessAsUser` with the token from the "main" Explorer.exe instance
- Bootstrapper instance elevates another instance and communicates back to parent when it needs to perform un-elevated actions
- Take advantage of Explorer bug and simply execute `"%windir\Explorer.exe" "c:\path\to\myapp.exe"`

All of those solutions have issues related to:

- Explorer might not be running (custom shell or Explorer crash)
- Explorer is running elevated
- Non-admin users elevate with a different administrator account with a different SID
- RunAs.exe has been used and your parent process is not the same as the "main" logon session nor Explorer.exe

Comment: If you're looking for the shell access token, don't hard-code Explorer. Call `GetShellWindow` to get the shell window and then `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get the shell process ID. A competent shell replacement will call `SetShellWindow` (or a direct `NtUserSetShellWindowEx` system call) to register itself as the active shell for the Windows session.